# Passing a Dynamic List of Values into Table.Combine

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have a relatively simple issue, which seems as if it should be achievable, but I have tried absolutely everything with no success.

Here is the situation:

Using Power Query inside Excel I would like to be able to **combine multiple queries** (lets call these: Query1, Query2 and Query3) into one single query using the Table.Combine function.

The only catch is that **the list of queries I will be combining will be dynamic** and dependant on another query (lets call this: QueryList)

For example, under certain circumstances QueryList will be:

- Query1
- Query2
- Query3

and under some other condtions QueryList may simply be:

- Query1
- Query3

What I would like to do is to be able to parse the value of QueryList into the Table.Combine Function:

eg. Table.Combine(#"QueryList")

and thereby allow dynamic consolidation of queries

Whats happening is that I am getting an error that states:

**Expression.Error: We cannot convert the value "Query1" to type Table.
Details:
    Value=Query1
    Type=Type**

**Update**:
I have tried variations of Table.ToList, using { } to create a list, TableFromlist, all with no success (normally errors complain about not being able to comvert from text to list or to table etc.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your QueryList would be {Query1, Query2} then Table.Combine(QueryList) would work.

Apparently, your QueryList is {"Query1", "Query2"}.

So the strings must be converted to tables, which can be done using Expression.Evaluate. As second parameter, you must supply a record with all possible queries, so the formula becomes, for Query1, Query2, Query3:

```
= Table.Combine(List.Transform(QueryList, each Expression.Evaluate(_, [Query1 = Query1, Query2 = Query2, Query3 = Query3])))
```

Comment: Sorry only replying now, this has worked great and has led me to an even more fluid and dynamic solution. I have created a field for the second parameter comprised of a text value.

The Text Value = [Query1 = Query1, Query2 = Query2, Query3 = Query3], which of course I applied to an Expression.Evaluate, which returned a list of records, which then went back into the solution you proposed above...